# Can anyone make me understand why visual studio is giving me this warning for my c++ code?

Tags: c++

I don't understand why the code has this warning:

> C6385: Reading invalid data from 'arr': the readable size is '160'
> bytes, but '200' bytes may be read.

This is a program to randomize numbers from the size of the string array and using these numbers to access elements within string array, 'arr'.

Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string arr[] = {"hey","music","ola","dang"};
   int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    int random;

    srand(time(0));
    for (int  i = 1; i <= size; i++)
    {
        random = rand() % ((size+1-1)+1);
        cout << random << "\t" << arr[random] << endl;
        

    }
    cout << endl;}
```

Comment: Because you go outside the range of the array. Arrays are 0 based, so the range of valid indexes are `0 .. size-1`

Comment: @ellaine fontamillas What is the meaning of subtraction and adding 1 in this expression size+1-1?

Comment: `random = rand() % ((size+1-1)+1);` should be `random = rand() % size);`

Comment: I'm impressed, the compiler was able to deduce the range of values in the indexing variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing of arrays in C++ starts from `0` instead of `1`. This means that we can only safely access the elements with indices from `0` upto `n - 1` where `n` is the number of elements in the array. Thus in your example, we can only safely access elements with index: `0`, `1`, `2` and `3`. And if we use any other positive integer(that is greater than `3`), then the program will have **undefined behavior**.

To **solve** this make sure that `random` always ranges from `0` upto `3` which you can do by changing `random = rand() % ((size+1-1)+1);` to:

```
random = rand() % (size);
```

So the modified code looks like:

```
int main()
{
   string arr[] = {"hey","music","ola","dang"};
   int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    int random;
    
    srand(time(0));
    for (int  i = 0; i < size; i++)//note the indexing starts from 0 
    {
        random = rand() % ((size)); //changed this 
        cout << random << "\t" << arr[random] << endl;
        

    }
    cout << endl;
    
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/acc1zTtAH)